# Most appropriate place to format data in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm working on a Rails application that will spit out a series of measurements that are taken over a period of days. Each measurement is stored as an individual record with a datetime and a value (plus other metadata)

When I query the data (using a specific date range) , I basically want the values grouped by DAY, so going from something like this:

```
datetime, value
datetime, value
datetime, value
datetime, value
datetime, value
datetime, value
```

to something like this:

```
date:
   time, value
   time, value
   time, value
date:
   time, value
   time, value
   time, value
```

I would return the data as JSON.

Now, my question is fairly high-level:

What is the best place in the application to make this transformation? Should I create a method in the model that returns data on this format? Should this be part of my controller action? Or should I do this on a jbuilder template?

I'd like to know what is considered the best practice, and why.

Thanks!

Comment: voting to close as opinion based, i think it depends on preference. for example some people might query in the controller and format in jbuilder, others don't use jbuilder and do both things in the controller, others use 'fat models' and do it all from model layer

Comment: But I'm sure all those approaches have different reasoning behind them, different pros and cons,  and will make more or less sense for different use cases. Wouldn't that make it a worth wile discussion?

Answer (score 2):

If we're dealing with data of a table of model, we should put the method in its own model. However, in order to make your model short, I recommend you create a module with single responsibility. Then including this module in corresponding model. Locating this module in models/concerns.
Hope it's useful.